# Internet download speed drops

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

I have a Toshiba Satellite C55-A laptop using Comcast wi-fi.  My download speed runs 25 to 35 mbps, until I, for example, connect to a video of even less than one minute.  At that point my speed drops to 0.6 and stays there until I reboot. Upload speeds show a similar pattern

In the meantime, my spouse is accessing the same wi-fi on his HP laptop, and his speed remains steady after accessing videos.

We're checking the speed using the XFINITY Speed Test.

Any suggestion for something I can do to maintain decent speed?

Comment: Knowing your OS would probably help anyone wanting to answer this question.